# Homestead npm install can't find package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

I've been trying for the past 2 days to run npm install so I can use laravel mix. After searching innumerous forums, repos and threads, I have not yet found a solution for my problem, which is when I cd into my laravel new created project and run `sudo npm install` I get the following error

```
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/Code/matt-fm/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/strip-ansi/package.json.2538224843
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/Code/matt-fm/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/strip-ansi/package.json.2538224843'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2019-07-12T12_52_05_433Z-debug.log
```

I have already removed the node_modules folder and tried running again, no success.
I tried removed the whole vagrant box and installing again, no success.
Cleaning the npm cache doesn't work neither.

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015122/is-there-a-solution-for-npm-install-error-in-laravel-homestead (without answer yet).

Comment: Posted the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015122/is-there-a-solution-for-npm-install-error-in-laravel-homestead

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem with homestead and after a lot of time waste, I found a solution for it. Simply use  `yarn install`

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install --force
```

It works for me

Comment: Please expand on why this is the answer, and how this should be implemented

Comment: @TimStack because I had the same problem and try to fix it. You should take the keyboard and type this command in command line and press enter.