# Is there a solution for npm install error in Laravel Homestead?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vagrant, homestead

- Windows 10,
- Homestead
- VirtualBox 6.0.8,
- Vagrant 2.2.5,
- node v12.5.0,
- npm  v6.10.1

All i'm trying to do is npm install command inside fresh installed Laravel app, but i keep getting errors.

After googling for two days and trying everything i found as a possible solution for npm install error i decided to try one more time reinstalling everything in hope that would fix my issue with npm install but unfortunately that didn't help either.

I tried deleting node_modules,
cleaning npm cache,
sudo npm install,
sudo npm install --no-bin-links,
updating node and npm but both were at latest version already,
changing VagrantFile based on some posts i've seen around internet(that never worked because than i'd get an error when i use vagrant up),
reinstalling everything,
running bash as admin,

I can't even remember everything I've done. This became really exhausing.

My log is 17k+ lines long. I'll just post last part where error happens.

```
17734 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/vue-test/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.2655513948'
17735 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/code/vue-test
17736 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
17737 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-links"
17738 verbose node v12.5.0
17739 verbose npm  v6.10.1
17740 error path /home/vagrant/code/vue-test/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.2655513948
17741 error code ENOENT
17742 error errno -2
17743 error syscall open
17744 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/vue-test/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/yargs-parser/package.json.2655513948'
17745 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
17746 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

My last hope is to ask if someone has a solution for this or i should just give up on Homestead.

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007524/homestead-npm-install-cant-find-package-json-file (without answer yet).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have grappled with the exact same issue for the last two days, except that I run on macOS (10.14). Using `yarn` instead of `npm` has finally allowed me to compile properly (see the doc for installing the package: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#alternatives-stable). It is a package manager that can use the same `package.json` entry point as `npm`, and you can simply try to run `yarn install` to perform the same action as `npm install` (for more in depth comparison between the commands, you can check out this link: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/). To be sure, it does not fix the main issue with npm, but at least it should allow you to work on your project while waiting for a more sound answer.

Comment: Thank you. I've realized yarn does the same thing much easier and without problems, but i forgot about this post. Hopefully your answer will help others with this problem. Cheers

Comment: This worked. I had to `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` (in the Homestead dir) to start anew and installed + ran `yarn` from *outside* the host machine (inside the project's directory). I don't think there's a way to make this work from within the host machine, sadly.

Comment: This answer saved my day, thank you so much <3

Answer (score 6):

What I've done to circunvemt this error is to `npm install` in the host-machine rather than on the guest through `vagrant ssh`. It seems that it's a problem with Windows locking the files from what I've researched. What I've done to bypass it, is:

1. `vagrant halt`
2. Inside your host (Windows), go to the shared folder for the website that you set-up in the `homestead.yaml` file.
3. Open `cmd` or `git bash` (as admin) from inside the folder (Shift+Right click or `cd` into it) and run `npm install`.
4. Voilà

Comment: yarn AND npm both give me errors when done in vagrant ssh. I also have to do it on the host machine instead. Seems odd but I haven't found another workaround

Answer (score 2):

```
vagrant halt
```

then just run npm, install && npm run dev, and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

```
npm install --force
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

i tried everything.. the only thing that will work for me, is setting up a samba server on my linux box...    from this i can edit the files directly on my windows machine..

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I searched for solution for a long time and nothing worked.

What worked is installing nodejs on the host machine and then running npm install in the project folder and then running npm run ... in the guest machine's project folder