# When should I execute commands on my host OS and when should I execute commands on my Laravel Homestead virtual machine?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am using Laravel Homestead and Vagrant to develop Laravel-applications and I'm lost in when to execute commands on my host OS and when to execute commands on my virtual machine (Laravel Homestead).

Recently I tried to install all the standard-dependencies of my fresh Laravel-project with NPM by executing the "npm install"-command on my Laravel Homestead virtual machine and it didn't allow me to do by giving me errors after errors about NPM not being able to find a file.

When I searched on how to fix it I saw a post from someone on this forum which told to execute "npm install" on the host OS.

When I did that, it worked but later i stumbled over another problem where I wanted to create a model by using the command "php artisan make:model".

I executed this command on my host OS and it didn't work but it did work on my virtual machine.

Every answer is appreciated!

Comment: 1. What is your host OS?
2. Try to copy package.json into a different folder in VM (which is not mounted to your host) and run npm install

Comment: 1: Ubuntu 20.10
2. I already succeeded to install all dependencies by running the commands on my host OS.

Comment: Please show your homestead configuration and important to configure ref.: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#configuring-shared-folders it could be related to some permissions issues.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Ok, the configuration looks good. Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/57007524/1205171 it looks like a common problem on npm.

Comment: My question doesn't relate to a NPM-problem. I'd like a clear explanation of when commands should be executed inside my VM and when on my host OS. You told me that Homestead is a completely isolated environment so that everything should be executed on the VM, but it succeeded me to install all dependencies by executing commands on my host OS instead of my VM so I don't get it when and why I should execute which command where.

Comment: Right. Homestead is an isolated environment and everything should be executed inside VM and in normal circumstances, everything should be working. If you are having issues inside VM it's a different question.

You need to understand why you are using VM in first place, it's to avoid cluttering  your host OS with random software and dependencies

Comment: Purpose of VM according to the Laravel docs:

Laravel strives to make the entire PHP development experience delightful, including your local development environment. Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.

Vagrant provides a simple, elegant way to manage and provision Virtual Machines. Vagrant boxes are completely disposable. If something goes wrong, you can destroy and re-create the box in minutes!

Comment: Your question was: where you should run your commands with Homestead , answer is given , any problems with VM itself is a different issue.

Comment: Right, my question is when I should run commands where with Laravel Homestead. Your answer is to run all commands inside the VM but I think that that can't be right because I once succeeded to do something by running a command on my host OS inside the Homestead folder because the VM gave me errors when running the same command. It could be that you are right, in that case I'd like a clear substantiation. If you post this as an answer I can accept is as the right answer.

Comment: Simply imagine that you are using remote-VM over ssh without sync. Where you would run your commands? The same rule applies to local-VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homestead is an isolated environment and everything should be executed inside VM and in normal circumstances, everything should be working.

simply imagine that you are using remote-VM over ssh without sync. Where you would run your commands? The same rule applies to local-VM.

Comment: Thank you for your addition! Could you explain your addition a bit more?

Also didn't it work to install all project-dependencies by executing "npm install" on the VM but it did work on my host OS. This also applies for "npm run dev".

Comment: Without extra information it’s hard to say anything, please provide logs